# Complement of a simple, connected graph

Tags: graph-theory

I have already proven that the complement of a simple, disconnected graph *G* results in a complementary graph that is always connected.

But what about the case for a simple, **connected** graph *G*? Is its complementary graph always disconnected? How would this be proven?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the complement of a connected graph can be either connected or non-connected.

There are even graphs that are *isomorphic* to their complements, such as the cycle graph with 5 vertices, or the path graph with 4 vertices.

Comment: I have been able to show that the complement of the connected graph is non-connected. Is there any effective way to show that the complement can be connected?

Comment: @user1713336: There must be something wrong with yuor proof, since I've just described two connected graphs whose complements are connected too.